# Process with covariance $E[Y_{t}Y_{s}]=a_{1}-a_{2}|t-s|$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

We have a centered Gaussian process $X_{t}$ where we have exact equality $$E[X_{t}X_{s}]=a_{1}-a_{2}|t-s|$$ for $|t-s|<\epsilon_{0}\ll \frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}$ and $a_{i}>0$.

> Q: I am curious if there is any other **concrete** Gaussian process $(Y_{s})_{s\in [0,\epsilon_{0}]}$  out there with the same exact covariance when $|t-s|<\epsilon_{0}$ for some $\epsilon_{0}>0$ (not asymptotical behaviour with error term, but exact equality).

It will be interesting if $Y_{t}$ is in terms of some known process like a functional of Brownian motion or a stationary solution of some SDE.

We are not concerned with $Y_{t}$ having different distribution than $X_{t}$(even though they do looked as Gaussian processes over $t\in [0,\epsilon']$ for $\epsilon'$ small enough). Our main concern is if such covariances have been studied in the literature or if we can devise one.

Some idea: start from $Y_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}f(r,t)dW_{r}$ and try to find a deterministic $f(r,t)$ with the desired covariance: by Ito isometry $\int_{0}^{s}f(r,s+h)f(r,s)ds=a_{1}-a_{2}h$.

**Our process**

Let $X_{\epsilon}(x)\sim N(0,\ln\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ with covariance:

[image]

For simplicity above we suppressed the $\epsilon$ and just let $X_{t}:=X_{\epsilon}(t)$.

Our particular process. Consider the hyperbolic measure $\lambda:=\frac{1}{y^{2}}dx dy$ in the upper half-plane and a White noise process W indexed by Borel sets of finite hyperbolic area:

$$\{A\subset \mathbb{H}: \lambda(A)<\infty; \sup_{(x,y),(x',y')\in A}|x-x'|<\infty\}$$

with covariance:

$$E[W(A_{1})W(A_{2})]:=\lambda(A_{1}\cap A_{2}).$$

Then let $X_{t}=W(V_{\epsilon}+t)$ for

$$V_{\epsilon}:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{H}: x\in [-1/4,1/4]\text{ and }max(2|x|,\epsilon)\leq y<1/2\}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Pólya’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), any even real-valued function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ with $f(\infty-)=0$ which is convex on $[0,\infty)$ is positive definite. So, any such function is the (auto)covariance function of a stationary Gaussian process; see e.g. [Section "Properties of the Autocovariance Function", page 2](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~rdavis/papers/VAG002.pdf).

Now just take any two different functions, $f_1$ and $f_2$, of the Pólya class such that $f_2(t)=1-|t|=f_2(t)$ for $|t|\le1/2$. Then the corresponding stationary Gaussian processes, say $(X_{1,t})$ and $(X_{2,t})$, with the covariance functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ will have different distributions. Therefore, these two processes will be different from each other.

---

To be more specific, note first here that, 
by vertical and horizontal re-scaling, without loss of generality $a_1=a_2=1$, so that
$$EX_sX_t=1-|t-s|\quad\text{if}\quad|t-s|\le u, \tag{1}$$
where $u\in(0,1)$. 
Let then 
$$Y_t:=B_{t+1}-B_t=\int_t^{t+1}dB_s,$$
where $(B_t)_{t\in\mathbb R}$ is the standard Brownian motion with $B_0=0$. Then 
$$EY_sY_t=1-|t-s|\quad\text{if}\quad|t-s|\le 1$$
(with $EY_sY_t=0$ if $|t-s|>1$),
so that 
$$EY_sY_t=EX_sX_t\quad\text{if}\quad|t-s|\le u,$$
as desired.

For more examples, take any $h\in(0,1)$ and let 
$$U_t:=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,(Y_{(1-h)t}+Z_{(1+h)t}),$$
where $(Z_t)$ is an independent copy of the Gaussian process $(Y_t)$. Then 
$$EU_sU_t=1-|t-s|=EY_sY_t \quad\text{if}\quad|t-s|\le1/(1+h)$$
and hence 
$$EU_sU_t=EX_sX_t \quad\text{if}\quad|t-s|\le\min[u,1/(1+h)],$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you Iosif.  The focus of the question was on finding some known process with the above mentioned covariance. Also I didn't write $\leq u$, I wrote $<u$. The distribution comment was just auxiliary, not the focus of the question.

Comment: If you like in your setting, you should think that the underlying interval we study is $[0,u]$ for $u<\frac{1}{2}$ and so we get the same distribution there by uniqueness of covariance for Gaussian processes.

Comment: @OOESCoupling : Your question was "if there is any other Gaussian process $Y_s$ out there with the same exact covariance when $|t-s|<\epsilon_0$ for some $\epsilon_0>0$". This question was fully answered by just modifying the process you had with such a covariance and thus using no additional knowledge. Your comment about the distinction between $<u$ and $\le u$ looks strange to me, since the covariance function of any 2nd-order process continuous at 0 is continuous everywhere, by Bochner's theorem. Anyhow, now I have given another version of the answer, based on Pólya's theorem.

Comment: Thank you Iosif. We are only looking at them as Gaussian processes restricted over $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ ignoring the rest.  Not as processes over the entire positive line, which one can devise many examples as you wrote.

Comment: The focus of the question is to construct/find some concrete known Gaussian process over the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ like an SDE solution.

Comment: @OOESCoupling : You keep changing the question. It was "if there is any other Gaussian process [with certain general properties]". Now, after getting full answers to the previous versions of your questions, you change the question to "It will be interesting if $Y_t$ is in terms of some known process like a functional of Brownian motion or a stationary solution of some SDE." An appropriate thing to do in such situations is, not to invalidate valid answers, but to post the additional questions separately. Otherwise, what did I spend my time for?

Comment: Thank you Iosif. I had this line "It will be interesting if Yt is in terms of some known process like a functional of Brownian motion or a stationary solution of some SDE" from the very beginning as you can check in the edit history.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you modify/delete the above answer to avoid confusion? Thank you Iosif.

Comment: Indeed, you had "It will be interesting ..." from the very beginning. I admit I had not noticed that. Almost all my attention was paid to your highlighted question: "if there is any other Gaussian process $(Y_{s})_{s\in [0,\epsilon_{0}]}$  out there with the same exact covariance when $|t-s|<\epsilon_{0}$ for some $\epsilon_{0}>0$". That question was fully answered. Why do you want me to delete the answer?

Comment: @IosifPineils Thank you Iosif. The above answers the different question of showing that $Y_{t}$ is not equal in distribution to $X_{t}$. That was not required in the question. The focus was to construct a concrete $Y_{t}$  that gives the covariance from the highlighted question and the title.

Comment: I wrote the "it will be interesting.." to contextualize the question's focus. So if you don't mind, please modify/delete the above answer to avoid confusion for others. Thank you Iosif.

Comment: @OOESCoupling : "The above answers the different question of showing that $Y_t$ is not equal in distribution to $X_t$. That was not required in the question." -- In a strange sense, you are correct here: my answers answer a significantly more nontrivial question than the one you asked. Indeed, your question was only "if there is any other Gaussian process" with certain general properties (say P) of its covariance function.

Comment: Previous comment continued:  Such a question could have been answered trivially, by taking, e.g. an independent copy $(Y_t)$ of your process $(X_t)$. Then $(Y_t)$ would obviously be different from $(X_t)$ and it would have the same covariance function, trivially with the same property P. So, both of my answers gave you much more than this trivial answer -- which latter would already, at least formally, completely answer your question.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Namely, both of my answers gave you Gaussian processes $(Y_t)$ that are, not only different from $(X_t)$, but also different from $(X_t)$ in distribution. Therefore, each of my answers answers your question more than completely.

Comment: @OOESCoupling : As for your "it will be interesting ...": I admitted that I had not noticed that. But, essentially, this does not matter much. What matters foremost is your highlighted, quite explicit question "Q: I am curious if there is any other Gaussian process [...]". The addition "it will be interesting ..." looks like just a wish which would be good to also have, in addition to the answer to the main question. Perhaps, you meant to make this additional wish your main question, but in fact you did not. I hope you can take a responsibility for that.

Comment: @OOESCoupling : I have added specific examples, in terms of stochastic integrals of the Brownian motion.

Answer (score 0):

By vertical and horizontal re-scaling, without loss of generality $a_1=a_2=1$, so that
$$EX_sX_t=1-|t-s|\quad\text{if}\quad|t-s|\le u, \tag{1}$$
where $u\in(0,1)$. 
Take any $h\in(0,1)$ and let 
$$U_t:=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,(X_{(1-h)t}+Y_{(1+h)t}),$$
where $(Y_t)$ is an independent copy of your Gaussian process $(X_t)$. Then 
$$EU_sU_t=1-|t-s|=EX_sX_t \tag{2}$$
if $|t-s|\le u/(1+h)$, as desired.

Moreover, letting $u$ take the largest possible value such that (1) still holds, we will see that the first equality in (2) will fail to hold if $|t-s|=u$, which shows that the distribution of $(U_t)$ is different from that of $(X_t)$. Therefore, the process $(U_t)$ is different from the process $(X_t)$.